# C programming. Structure is never set to NULL, why?

Tags: c

I cannot figure out why my iterator object which is a struct is not set to NULL.
Here is piece of code:

```
void * NextItem(SLIteratorPtr iter)
{
    DestroyFunction destroy = iter -> list -> destroy;

    if(iter -> currentNode -> next == NULL){
        iter -> currentNode -> ptrCounter--;
        if (iter -> currentNode -> ptrCounter < 1){
            destroy(iter -> currentNode -> value);
            NodePtr temp = iter -> currentNode;
            free(temp);
        }
        iter = NULL; // <--- HERE IT MUST BE SET TO NULL
        return NULL;
    }

    ... some other code here
}
```

PRINT FUNCTION in main:

```
void listPrintIter(SLIteratorPtr iterator){
    int i;
       while (iterator != NULL){ // <- NEVER NULL HERE, INFINITE LOOP
        i = *((int *)(SLGetItem(iterator)));
        SLNextItem(iterator); //<-- HERE MY ITERATOR MUST BE SET TO NULL IN THE END, BUT IT IS NOT
    }
}
```

So I am running into error when iterator stops on the last entry and is never being set to NULL. SO it goes again into SLNextItem and try to do free(temp); which is already deleted.. thus I run into error. But the actual problem that iter = NULL does not set my iterator to NULL in main. Though it sets values as expected. I am confused. Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm going to guess here, since you've shared nearly nothing about the **types** in this code, `iterator = SLNextItem(iterator);`

Comment: You never re-assign to `iterator`.

Comment: @WhozCraig no, SLNExtItem return value which iterator points to. But I change iterator inside this function. I do not care about value of the next item, I care about iterator to be advanced by one

Comment: We could guess all day long, without knowing the actual *type* content of `SLIterator`, `SLIteratorPtr` ( though we could likely guess on that one), etc, the best you'll get is wags (wild-ass-guesses) on this. If you have a "why doesn't this code work?" question, you need to provide enough info to make a reasonable assessment. in C++ iterators are *value* types, directly copyable, etc. How you're managing (or trying to manage) this in C is anyones guess without code to clarify. luser droog's answer makes the most sense knowing what little we have to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an extra level of indirection in order to change the value of the caller's pointer. This is because C does not have "references" per se.

```
void * NextItem(SLIteratorPtr *iter)
{
    DestroyFunction destroy = (*iter) -> list -> destroy;

    if((*iter) -> currentNode -> next == NULL){
        (*iter) -> currentNode -> ptrCounter--;
        if ((*iter) -> currentNode -> ptrCounter < 1){
            destroy((*iter) -> currentNode -> value);
            NodePtr temp = (*iter) -> currentNode;
            free(temp);
        }
        *iter = NULL; // <--- HERE caller's ptr MUST BE SET TO NULL
        return NULL;
    }

    ... some other code here
}
```

And call it with the address.

```
void listPrintIter(SLIteratorPtr iterator){
    int i;
       while (iterator != NULL){ // <- NEVER NULL HERE, INFINITE LOOP
        i = *((int *)(SLGetItem(iterator)));
        SLNextItem(&iterator); //<-- HERE MY ITERATOR MUST BE SET TO NULL IN THE END, BUT IT IS NOT
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do *iter = NULL I have error  "Assigning to 'struct SLIterator' from incompatible type 'void *' "    and when I do &iterator I have warning 
"Incompatible pointer types passing 'SLIteratorPtr *' (aka 'struct SLIterator **') to parameter of type 'SLIteratorPtr' (aka 'struct SLIterator *'); remove & "

Comment: +1, without knowing anything else beyond what we have, this easily makes the most sense when needing by-reference modification to an in/out parameter.

Comment: @PutinHuylo The type of the parameter in the function's signature would also need to change. `void * NextItem(SLIteratorPtr * iter)` Having the pointer concealed by the typedef obscures things somewhat, but it is the double-pointer `**` that I'm talking about. That's what allows you to change the regular pointer `*` in the caller.